# React Redux passing parameters via functions from child components to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488036/react-redux-form-using-child-components-with-child-components-that-have-multiple) on this and I believe Dennis who answered the question gave the answer I thought was correct. I cant figure out how to pass variables back to the parent function correctly...

Here is the code I want to fix.

**Child of a Child Component**

First there is a child of a child component. This will set the sort direction of the list if you click on it. Its using "onSortDirectionChange" function and should set the sort direction by setting a variable "sortDirection".

```
const GlyphiconDirectionChange = (props) => {
  const { onSortDirectionChange } = props

  return (
    <span>
      {onSortDirectionChange === 'Ascending' ?
          <span onClick={() => onSortDirectionChange('Ascending')} className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes'></span>
        :
          <span onClick={() => onSortDirectionChange('Descending')} className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt'></span>
      }
    </span>
  )
}
```

Click on the glyphicon next to the header name and it should change the direction of the list. Simple component.

**Child component**

Its parent, but the child of "ClientContainer" is TableHeaders. "GlyphiconDirectionChange" sits in this component to display the up or down glyphicon that you can click...

```
     <GlyphiconDirectionChange onSortDirectionChange={onSortDirectionChange} />
```

**Parent Component**

ClientContainer is the top component (actions etc will be split off later - they are in there now for simplicity). In here TableHeaders is displayed as follows:

```
        <TableHeaders onSortByChange={this.handleSortBy}
        onSortDirectionChange={this.handleSortDirection}
        query={query}
        currentPage={currentPage}
```

Note the second line is the function from the bottom component.

It is referring to "HandleSortDirection".

```
  handleSortDirection = (values = {}) => {
  const { sortDirection, query, sortBy  } = this.props
  values.query = values.query || ''
  const searchParams = {
    query,
    sortBy,
    sortDirection,
    ...values,
    currentPage: 1,
  }
  console.log('changeHeaders()!', values, searchParams)
  this.fetchClients(searchParams)
}
```

**Problem**
How do you set variables in the "child of a child component" and move them through to the "HandleSortDirection" function.

I am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'query' on string 'Descending'

I need the "searchParams" variable "sortDirection" to be set to either "Ascending" or "Descending" and be used correctly in my function..

How do I pass my sortDirection variable correctly to the function in the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How do you set variables in the "child of a child component" and move them through to the "HandleSortDirection" function."

You are already doing this but you have a typo.

`values.query = values.query || ''`

This line is erroring because `values` is equal to `'Descending'`. You are passing in a string here from your child of child component, and it is being passed up the chain of callbacks til it gets here.

Remove that line and replace it with
`const direction = values;`
and then pass `direction` in place of `sortDirection,` in searchParams.

Comment: No errors and it worked.. I dont know why the console.log above gives "changeHeaders()! Object {0: "D", 1: "e", 2: "s", 3: "c", 4: "e", 5: "n", 6: "d", 7: "i", 8: "n", 9: "g", query: "", sortBy: "LastName", direction: "Descending", currentPage: 1}". Could you clarify why its broken the string into seperate characters.. and is it something I have done.. also not sure how putting "direction" in "searchParams" resulted in sortDirection: "Descending" - wondering if you might elaborate.

Comment: The code I suggested is not changing `sortDirection` at all, `sortDirection` is a prop which means it is immutable and cannot be changed. Instead of passing an immutable prop to `searchParams`, I suggested to just set a variable called `direction` and pass the variable instead. 

your call `this.fetchClients(searchParams)` does not care about the prop called `sortDirection` it only cares about what is within `searchParams` and since `direction` is within `searchParams` now, it works.

Comment: The console.log output being separated into characters is unrelated to anything I suggested here. I think that it is another bug elsewhere in your code.